# Error Number: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value in my SQL error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

i have display error like this 1292  Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value 
 this is my delete operation function code in code igniter model

```
public function delete_marks($s_id){
           $this->db->where_not_in('student_id', $s_id);
           return  $this->db->delete('student_marks');
       }
```

and its display error

> Error Number: 1292
>   Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '305,304'
>   DELETE FROM student_marks WHERE student_id NOT IN ('305,304')

because of in this portion  `'305,304'`  single quota `' '` auto added
so its display 1292 error 
how to i fix it?

Comment: `$this->db->where_not_in('student_id',explode(',', $s_id));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your  `$s_id` is string. In CI, `where_not_in` or `where_in` you have to pass array.

```
public function delete_marks($s_id){
    $s_id = explode(",", $s_id);
    $this->db->where_not_in('student_id', $s_id);
    return  $this->db->delete('student_marks');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `where_not_in`  you have to pass an array.

```
public function delete_marks($s_id){
    $this->db->where_not_in('student_id',explode(',', $s_id));
    return  $this->db->delete('student_marks');
}
```